# Failed to open a session for the virtual machine win-7

Tags: virtualization

Ubuntu 16.04.1 is showing this error while running virtual machine:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine win-7. The virtual
machine 'win-7' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit
code 1 (0x1).

Result Code:  NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component:  MachineWrap
Interface:  IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown all your VM's.

1. Go to your `/home/$user/.VirtualBox/` folder
2. Find the file `VirtualBox.xml-prev`
3. `mv VirtualBox.xml VirtualBox.xml.bak`
4. `mv VirtualBox.xml-prev VirtualBox.xml`

If this fails, you can reverse it with `rm VirtualBox.xml && mv VirtualBox.xml.bak VirtualBox.xml`

Try restarting VirtualBox

*Other possible fixes:*

- `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

or

- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`